# Excel Add In Start Up (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, message, show, startup

I just created a new add in for Microsoft Excel within Visual Studio.

Creating the file generated a private void function called `ThisAddIn_Startup`, which I figure should allow me to run code when the add in first runs.

My current code is as follows:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Startup");
}
```

This is seriously the only thing I have added to this project other than:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I'm simply testing to see if the message box will actually start when I open up Excel and/or install the add-in. Everything is using default settings. This message simply won't show. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried writing to a file instead of showing a message box?

Comment: Why would I want to do that?  I just want the add in to show a message.  Besides, a message box is so much simpler then creating and destroying file streams.